# Getting a value from text input field, then displaying on POST

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm trying to get a value from a form, then display it on posting of the form. I can get the value to appear in the second text field, once I have chosen an option using the Ajax Auto-Select, but how do I get that value shown stored into a variable for display on posting? This is what I have been trying -

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'getentity') {
    $value= $entity;
    $content .= '<div>'.$value.' hello</div>';
    }

<form method="post" action="?">
 <input type="text" name="TownID_display" size="50" onkeyup="javascript:ajax_showOptions(this,\'getEntitiesByLetters\',event)">
<input type="text" name="TownID" id="TownID_display_hidden" value="'.$entity.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="getentity" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Find"/>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" name="TownID" id="TownID_display_hidden" value="<?php $value = $entity; echo $entity; ?>" />
```

and its better to use like this

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'getentity') {
    $value= $_POST['TownID'];
    $content .= '<div>'.$value.' hello</div>';
    }
```

it should work.

Comment: No that doesn't work, sorry. Thanks though. The value then just becomes: <?php echo etc>

Comment: @EliteExplorer do you want to display the text typed in second input tag?

Comment: Thank you, your second chunk of code made it work! I can leave the value empty with that, and the result is it posts the value I wanted along with the hello. Thank you so much! Now I can start practising on the second part which involves lots of MySQL queries :o